# Is there a way to add a document to Firestore ONLY when a user has been successfully created in Firebase?

Tags: android, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-authentication

Essentially I am trying to create a new user using Firebase Authentication but I also want to add the user's info into Firestore as a document but ONLY IF the new user was successfully created, otherwise the code where the document is being created should not be reached.

```
firebaseAuth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email, password)
            .addOnCompleteListener(this, new OnCompleteListener<AuthResult>() {
                @Override
                public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<AuthResult> task) {
                    if(task.isSuccessful()) {
                        Toast.makeText(SignUpActivity.this, "Registered successfully", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    } else {
                        Toast.makeText(SignUpActivity.this, "Could not register. Please try again.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 11) {
                            SignUpActivity.this.recreate();
                        } else {
                            SignUpActivity.this.finish();
                            SignUpActivity.this.startActivity(SignUpActivity.this.getIntent());
                        }
                    }
                }
            });

    Map<String, Object> user = new HashMap<>();
    user.put("email", email);
    user.put("fName", fName);
    user.put("lName", lName);

    if(studentRadioButton.isChecked()) {
        user.put("studentNum", email.substring(1, 9));
    }

    firebaseFirestore.collection("users").document(firebaseAuth.getUid()).set(user);
```

One of the methods I've tried (as shown below) is to recreate the current activity but it just goes back to where it started and ultimately moves onto the code where it creates the document. With all the other methods I've tried, it's as if I can't put anything into the onComplete method within the onCompleteListener other than a Toast popup. Please help!

Comment: "ONLY IF the new user was successfully created" , so why don't you write your firestore code inside  `if(task.isSuccessful()) {`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As aryan commented: to ensure the document only gets created when the user has been created in Firebase Authentication, move the code into the `if`:

```
firebaseAuth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email, password)
    .addOnCompleteListener(this, new OnCompleteListener<AuthResult>() {
        @Override
        public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<AuthResult> task) {
            if(task.isSuccessful()) {
                Toast.makeText(SignUpActivity.this, "Registered successfully", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                Map<String, Object> user = new HashMap<>();
                user.put("email", email);
                user.put("fName", fName);
                user.put("lName", lName);

                if(studentRadioButton.isChecked()) {
                    user.put("studentNum", email.substring(1, 9));
                }

                firebaseFirestore.collection("users").document(firebaseAuth.getUid()).set(user);

            } else {
                Toast.makeText(SignUpActivity.this, "Could not register. Please try again.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 11) {
                    SignUpActivity.this.recreate();
                } else {
                    SignUpActivity.this.finish();
                    SignUpActivity.this.startActivity(SignUpActivity.this.getIntent());
                }
            }
        }
    });
```